# Pi stopped connecting to wifi in fedberry?

Tags: pi-3, wifi, pi-3b+, wireless, fedora

I'm using a rpi3 b+ and fedberry 27.
I had connected to wifi previously, now it suddenly stopped working. In edit connections I shows that I have my wifi network as a saved connection and my password is correct. 
 How do I fix this and connect to wifi?

Comment: did you make any changes before the wifi stopped connecting?

Comment: No, I just didn't use it for a few days.

Comment: Sorry, bu your question is of the sort: "my car suddenly stops. What shall I do?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted my rpi a couple of times and the wifi started working.